# How to use a variable in a function from an earlier list in nested list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, opencv, python

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="D:\\Tesseract\\tesseract.exe"
i = cv2.imread('1.png')
himg,wimg,_ = i.shape
[cv2.putText(i, b[0], (x, himg - y + 25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (50, 50, 255), 2) for x,y,w,h in  [[int(x) for x in n ]for n in  [[a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]] for a in [b.split(' ') for b in pytesseract.image_to_boxes(i).splitlines()]]]]
cv2.imshow('',i)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

in the line `[cv2.putText(i, b[0], (x, himg - y + 25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (50, 50, 255), 2) for x,y,w,h in  [[int(x) for x in n ]for n in  [[a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]] for a in [b.split(' ') for b in pytesseract.image_to_boxes(i).splitlines()]]]]` , I get an error mainly because I am trying to use the the variable 'b' in my final function from an earlier list in the list comprehension.
I know this because `[cv2.rectangle(i, (x,himg- y), (w,himg -h), (265,0,0), 2) for x,y,w,h in  [[int(x) for x in n ]for n in  [[a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]] for a in [b.split(' ') for b in pytesseract.image_to_boxes(i).splitlines()]]]]`
Works perfectly fine. Pls tell a way to achieve the desired result while maintaining the list comprehension.

Comment: sometimes comprehensions make a solution more complicated rather than less...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this alternate approach does what you seek to do:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="D:\\Tesseract\\tesseract.exe"

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale = 1
color = (50, 50, 255)
thickness = 2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
image_height, image_width = image.shape

for row in pytesseract.image_to_boxes(image).splitlines():
    cells = row.split(' ')
    text = cells[0]
    x, y, w, h = map(int, cells[1:5])
    origin = (x, image_height - y + 25)
    cv2.putText(image, text, origin, font, fontScale, color, thickness)

cv2.imshow('',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: No, I want to maintain the list comprehension

Comment: What is the motivation to restructure yourself to a comprehensiin?